# woocommerce_checkout_order_processed hook executing function twice

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, api

I already asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46686075/woocommerce-checkout-order-processed-hook-executing-function-twice) in StackOverflow but I think this could be the right place to ask.

---

I have attached a function to the `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` hook:

```
//check if woocommerce is acive
if (in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins')))) {
    add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'wc_on_place_order');
}
```

The `wc_on_place_order` function is to be executed after the user clicks on the <kbd>PLACE ORDER</kbd> button. However, it's so odd that the function is executed twice.

My `wc_on_place_order` function calls an external api written in C#:

```
function wdm_send_order_to_ext( $order_id ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // get order object and order details
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id ); 

    // get product details
    $items = $order->get_items();
    //return $items;

    $products = array();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        array_push($products, 
            array('userid' => $order->user_id, 'descr' => $item['name'], 'amt' => (float)$item['line_total'])
        );
    }

    //passing $products to external api using `curl_exec`
    . . . .

    //on successful call, the page should be showing an `alert`, however, it does not
    // the handle response    
    if (strpos($response,'ERROR') !== false) {
            print_r($response);
    } else {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert($response)</script>";
    }
}
```

After debugging on C# api, I noticed that it the service is being called twice, thus, the checkout is being saved twice to the api database. Is there something wrong with the `wc_on_place_order` function or is `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` called twice when clicking the <kbd>PLACE ORDER</kbd>?

Interestingly, adding `return $items` after `$items = $order->get_items()` somehow, the C# api was only called once:

```
// get product details
$items = $order->get_items();
return $items; //this line
```

Why is that so?

One more question I would like to ask, is `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` the right hook I should use? I have been searching the web for the correct hook to use and it seems that `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` is used in most post. I can't use the `woocommerce_thankyou` hook as it is also calling the api if I refresh the page.

Any idea will be really appreciated.

**EDIT:**

This question already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46686075/woocommerce-checkout-order-processed-hook-executing-function-twice).

**EDIT 2:**

Though the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46688401/7291240) in my stackoverflow question fixes the double calling problem, it seems like you can't throw an error and stop the woocommerce from redirecting to the "thank you" page from this hook. I think this hook is not intended if you want to do some other checking logics before proceeding to the actual **"Purchase Success"***.